# Is there a way to remove 3d touch shortcut Icon

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I there a way to have only text on `UIApplicationShortcutItem`  ?

I have an idea to put empty .png file, but wondering if there more elegant way exist

```
<key>UIApplicationShortcutItems</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
            <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeSearch</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
            <string>Search</string>
            <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
            <string>Search</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Please check for dynamic way adding of 3d touch.

Comment: @Arasuvel I need static items